# Visualization random sample with displaCy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, spacy

How can I visualize using displaCy in a dataframe? I have a data called `taks_output` and want to visualize a sample of the column `msg_lower`?

What I did:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy 
import nltk
from spacy import displacy

df = task_output['msg_lower']
df = df.sample(n=1787)
displacy.render(df,  style='dep', jupyter=True, options={'distance': 90})
```

And I get an error:

> Invalid object passed to displaCy: Can only visualize Doc or Span objects, or dicts if set to manual=True.

What can I do?

Comment: As indicated in the error message, you can't pass a dataframe. Get the Doc out of the dataframe and you should be fine.

Comment: @polm23 But how can i do this?

Comment: same thing on spaCy forums https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10800